# .Net IHttpClientFactory usage with Singleton

Tags: .net, .net-core, ihttpclientfactory

So if I have a class registered through DI as a Single Instance (Singleton) and I inject the IHttpClientFactory inside the class.

```
 class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public MyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
        public async Task Call()
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
            await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://test.com"));
        }
    }
```

Is it correct that on every call to the function Call I create a new client using the _clientFactory.CreateClient? or should I create one client in the constructor wth the factory and then re-use that for every function call?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a client each time you call `MyService.Call()` method. No need to dispose it once you're done with it. `IHttpClientFactory` manages the resources used by `HttpClient`s for you.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management):

> A new `HttpClient` instance is returned each time `CreateClient` is called on the `IHttpClientFactory`. An `HttpMessageHandler` is created per named client. The factory manages the lifetimes of the `HttpMessageHandler` instances.
>
> `IHttpClientFactory` pools the `HttpMessageHandler` instances created by the factory to reduce resource consumption. An `HttpMessageHandler` instance may be reused from the pool when creating a new `HttpClient` instance if its lifetime hasn't expired.
>
> ...
>
> `HttpClient` instances can generally be treated as .NET objects not requiring disposal. Disposal cancels outgoing requests and guarantees the given `HttpClient` instance can't be used after calling `Dispose`. `IHttpClientFactory` tracks and disposes resources used by `HttpClient` instances.
>
> Keeping a single `HttpClient` instance alive for a long duration is a common pattern used before the inception of `IHttpClientFactory`. **This pattern becomes unnecessary** after migrating to `IHttpClientFactory`.